# i cant reinstall ubuntu mounting filesystem.squashfs failed: no such device

Tags: boot

[image]

[image]

i have installed Ubuntu before and something has filling up the ubuntu drive. then i removed the /var to free up memory on boot shell then Ubuntu still runs but i cant install any app. then i reinstall Ubuntu but got error like this image. I am sure that the usbbootable is not faulty and  .iso file too because i can install Ubuntu in another laptop( i use refus and etcher to make usbboot ). Now, partition which contain last ubuntu has been deleted and i am trying reinstall Ubuntu.

My laptop is thinkpad p50 and i used Ubuntu 22.04 amd64 LTS dekstop

Comment: Sorry ... you deleted `/var` from your Ubuntu installation?

Comment: @matigo i deleted /var from shell when i am booted ubuntu and got failed out of memory and could't run gnom